# PHP PDO update statement fails

Tags: php, session, pdo, sql-update

The below sql UPDATE statement returns an error but I'm unable to see why:

```
Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 6
```

I already did a vardump of the array that I pass to bind the parameters but I see nothing unusual. The correct values are passed and I double checked for typos. 
What I try to accomplish is to auto-generate a username based on firstname - lastname and user_id after insertion into the database.
Perhaps additional question: do you see any harm in that and if so, what is your suggestion? 
I'm still in PHP learning phase.

Thanks.

```
        ...

        //Autogenerate user_name based on first name, last name and user_id (auto-increment) 
        $query_username = "
            UPDATE user_tbl 
                SET
                    user_name = :username 
                WHERE
                    user_id = :userid
            ) 
        ";

        // The parameter values 
        $query_params_username = array(
            ':username' => $_SESSION['user']['first_name'].".".$_SESSION['user']['last_name'].$_SESSION['user']['user_id'],
            ':userid' => $_SESSION['user']['user_id']
        );

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query against the database 
            $stmt_username = $db->prepare($query_username);
            $stmt_username->execute($query_params_username);
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        {       
             //Not to be used in production 
             die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        }

        $_SESSION['user']['username'] = $_SESSION['user']['first_name'].".".$_SESSION['user']['last_name'].$_SESSION['user']['user_id'];
```

Comment: I think you're missing an opening `(` at the top or one that doesn't belong `)`.

Comment: It's kinda weird, there is nothing on line 6. But I'm sure that the error is thrown after the try block because of a few echo/die tests I did.

Comment: You have a closing `)` after `user_id = :userid`, but no opening `(` at `$query_username = "`.

Comment: Hehe crap. Let me try to remove that and see if it works :-$. I'll delete the question if it works to keep SO system clean. Must've been blind or something...

Comment: Try either adding a `(` or delete the `)` where I mentioned above Kim.

Comment: It's up to you Kim. Try that, let me know either way, and if you feel you want to delete the question, *then so be it.* ;-)

Comment: Plus I could make it as an answer and make some extra points lol! I'm just at the threshold of reaching my big **2K** ;-)

Comment: Yep, it works now Fred Lol!! I don't think that this question can help anyone, as the answer was the bracket. Thanks for your help; staring too long at code makes one blind sometimes, I was looking at it for some time... But I don't mind accepting your answer :-)

Comment: You're welcome Kim, I was happy to have been of help. To be honest, I'm just starting to learn SQL myself, however I'm no stranger to the rest of the coding world, as it were. So, you removed the `)` after `user_id = :userid`?

Comment: Yep, that was all I did, and it works now :-)

Comment: Great, well I found it useful myself in the learning process. All the best Kim! Cheers

Comment: Just an added note Kim: If you could mark the answer as being accepted, please click the checkmark to mark it as being closed Kim, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a closing parentheses after `user_id = :userid`

Try the following:

```
$query_username = "
    UPDATE user_tbl 
        SET
            user_name = :username 
        WHERE
            user_id = :userid
";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this:

```
$query_username = "
                     UPDATE  `user_tbl` 
                     SET     `user_name` = :username 
                     WHERE   `user_id` = :userid
                  ";
```

There seems to be a lost `)` character in your code.

Comment: Thanks Laurent that's indeed correct, stupid me. I'll upvote your and Fred's reply (if he replies). I don't know who was first, so I'll keep the church in the middle (Dutch expression).

Comment: @KimGysen By the timestamp, we were pretty much even. I will upvote as well. And I know of that expression. I have Dutch friends. *"It's only fair"*.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have already upvoted this answer, so someone must have downvoted it. I don't know why though. Perhaps due to the fact that Laurent mentioned the single quotes. I don't believe it hurts though...